# Google spread sheets, query, combine concate columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I did a search and it seems I can't use concate in the query SQL string.

How can I combine two columns that have only strings in each row:

```
C = Firstname
D = Lastname
Combine = Firstname Lastname
```

> =query(RAW!1:1000;"  SELECT * ,concate(C,D) WHERE B='"&C2&"' ";-2)

Answer (score 0):

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(C:C&" "& D:D)
```

Comment: @F T I'm not getting you. Share your sheet.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bvtcm1MZ1Hy6F0QWoYrOYmaBqIWYEvw2KaGj6dCbxFE/edit?usp=sharing) @anonymous

Comment: @F T `=ARRAYFORMULA(query({RAW!A1:C5\RAW!D1:D5&RAW!E1:E5};" SELECT *  WHERE Col2='"&C2&"' "))`